# language localization in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to convert my MERN app into a local language with i18n dependency, but only with keys. but not able to convert my app completely, means how to translate each component of my app into the local language? please help
or
how to do language localization in React?

Comment: I can highly recommend i18next for React: https://react.i18next.com/